# How to creat an auto redirect link using php or html

Tags: php, html, url, redirect, hyperlink

I want to make an auto redirect link by some query for example:

MyDomain.com/go?domain=**AnyDomain.com** will auto redirect to https://moz.com/researchtools/ose/links?site=**AnyDomain.com**

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, updated now. Working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
<html><body><script><!--
document.location="https://moz.com/researchtools/ose/links?site=<?= htmlspecialchars($_GET["domain"]) ?>";
//--></script></body></html>
```

So post your data to

MyDomain.com/go?domain=AnyDomain.com

and **domain** will be captured with my script and automatically redirected to (example) https://moz.com/researchtools/ose/links?site=AnyDomain.com

Comment: That's my problem, how to detect AnyDomain.com from the source url?
Sorry I'm new on coding

Comment: @Gian, please, could you check my answer as the correct one? There is a small **v** check at the side of my answer. I will plus one for it. Thank you very much. Glad that worked.

Answer (score 0):

To do this with php you can use the [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function:

```
header("Location: https://moz.com/researchtools/ose/links?site=".$_GET['domain']);
```